# Snapper to only take snapshots if something has changed, or at a lower cadence

Tags: debian, btrfs, snapshot

I'm using [snapper](http://snapper.io/) for automatic timeline snapshots of my filesystem.  The issue I have is that it continues to take hourly snapshots even when nothing on the filesystem has changed, which causes the disks to spin up once per hour.  Ideally I want them to stay spun down if nothing is changing.

Does anyone know if I can:

- Configure snapper to only take a snapshot if something has changed since the last snapshot?

**Or**

- Reduce the cadence of the regular timeline snapshots from something less frequent than hourly?

Answer (score 0):

To change the cadence, you could disable

```
/etc/cron.hourly/snapper
```

copy it to another location and add/create a new cronjob in /etc/crontab or under /etc/cron.d.